How to wait till a website is loaded in flutter_inappwebview?
I am beginner and I am using flutter_inappwebview's(version 6.0.0) HeadlessInAppWebview class to make a function that will:

open a website
then wait for it to load
then grab some content from the page and return it.

I thought i could wait for it to load like webviewController.loadUrl().then().
But it didn't work
How can i wait for it to load or am I supposed to do it in a different way?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To achieve this functionality using the flutter_inappwebview, You need to add the callbacks for onLoadStart, onProgressChanged & onLoadStop
This is the code i used in my project
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:snopixie/constants.dart';

class FlutterInWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterInWebViewPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlutterInWebViewPage> createState() => _FlutterInWebViewPageState();
}

class _FlutterInWebViewPageState extends State<FlutterInWebViewPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  init() async {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  bool isLoading = true;
  int progress = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Check if webview can go back
        if (await webViewController!.canGoBack()) {
          // Go back
          webViewController!.goBack();
          // Return false so this webview won't be popped
          return false;
        } else {
          // Let system handle back button
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              InAppWebView(
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                  url: Uri.parse("https://example.com/"),
                ),
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                    progress = 0;
                  });
                },
                onProgressChanged: (controller, p) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = p < 100;
                    progress = p;
                  });
                },
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                    progress = 0;
                  });
                },
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {},
              ),
              if (isLoading)
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(primary),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      value: progress / 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you give a simple example code with explanation on how i can implement my function?

instead of webviewController.loadUrl().then(() => {}) use the onLoadStop: (controller, url) {} in Flutter InAppWebView
and write your logic inside the onLoadStop callback

But how can I add it in a function?
